# Rails Devise invitable redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im playing around with the Devise invitable gem: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

It's working fine.

But how do i redirect to a specific page on a successful invitation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [devise invitable readme](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable):

> After an invitation is accepted, the invitee will be redirected to **after_accept_path_for(resource)**, which is the same path as after_sign_in_path_for by default. If you want to override the path, override invitations controller and define after_accept_path_for method. This is useful in the common case that a user is invited to a specific location in your application. More on Devise's README, "Controller filters and helpers" section.

Answer (score 0):

Since devise_invitable is based upon devise, I guess you can use this:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in